# Sending multiple attachment files by email

Tags: 8, emails

I am trying to send multiple files attached to an email, but I can only make it work when only one file is attached. I am using mandrill mailer, btw.

Here is the code I have on a form submit:

```
    $attachments = [];
    if ($files) {
      foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $file = File::load($value['target_id']);
        $attachments[] = [
          'filepath' => $file->getFileUri(),
          'filename' => $file->getFileName(),
          'filemime' => $file->getMimeType(),
        ];
      }
    }

    $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
    $module = 'mymodule';
    $langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();
    $params = [
      'subject' => 'Application from ' . $applying_user->get('field_first_name')->value . ' ' . $applying_user->get('field_last_name')->value,
      'candidate_name' => $applying_user->get('field_first_name')->value . ' ' . $applying_user->get('field_last_name')->value,
      'attachments' => $attachments,
    ];
    $mailManager->mail($module, 'email_application', $user_email, $langcode, $params);
```

Then using hook_mail():

```
 case 'email_application':
      $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
      $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
      $message['body'][] = buildBodyMail($params);
      $message['attachments'] = $params['attachments'];
      break;
```

The email I receive does not have any attachment, even though there are 4 files in this particular example meant to be attached.

If I change the code to:

```
    if ($files) {
      foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
        $file = File::load($value['target_id']);
        $attachments = [
          'filepath' => $file->getFileUri(),
          'filename' => $file->getFileName(),
          'filemime' => $file->getMimeType(),
        ];
      }
    }
```

...then it attaches only the last file of the set. It seems that

```
$message['attachments']
```

does not allow a multidimensional array. I've seen examples with

```
$message['params']['attachments'] = $params['attachments'];
```

and have tried but to no avail.

How can multiple files be attached to an email? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with something like `$message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment'];
      $message['params']['attachments'][] = $params['attachment2'];`

Comment: Tried that but does not attach even a single file; only thing that has worked for me is: $message['attachments'], not $message['params']['attachments']. But again, not for multiple file attachments...

Answer (score 0):

Try as $message['attachments'][] instead of $message['attachments']
example
$message['attachments'][] = $params['attachment2'];

Comment: Doesn't work. 
`$attachment = [
      'filepath' => 'sites/default/files/file1.pdf',
      'filename' => 'file1.pdf',
      'filemime' => 'application/pdf'
    ];

    $attachment2 = [
      'filepath' => 'sites/default/files/file2.pdf',
      'filename' => 'file2.pdf',
      'filemime' => 'application/pdf'
    ]; 
$message['attachments'][] = $attachment;`
...does not send any attachment.